# CodingBat difference in Code

Tags: java, difference

So I was having severe difficulty answering this question, http://codingbat.com/prob/p186177.

> Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the number of times that sub appears in the string, without the sub strings overlapping.
>
> - `strCount("catcowcat", "cat") → 2`
> - `strCount("catcowcat", "cow") → 1`
> - `strCount("catcowcat", "dog") → 0`

So I decided to google the answer, study it. Erase it and try myself. I came up with.

```
public int strCount(String str, String sub) {
    if(sub.length() > str.length())
        return 0;
    if(str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub))
        return 1 + strCount(str.substring(str.length()),sub);
    return strCount(str.substring(1),sub);
}
```

while the answer is:

```
public int strCount(String str, String sub) {
if (str.length() < sub.length()) return 0;
if (str.substring(0, sub.length()).equals(sub))
    return 1 + strCount(str.substring(sub.length()), sub);
return strCount(str.substring(1), sub);
```

}

I have no idea why I've been looking at the difference for the past 10 minutes, and cannot understand why when I run my code it only returns 0 or 1 as an answer. Can anybody find the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The `strCount` has different arguments. `(sub.length()), sub);` to `(str.length()),sub);`.

For future reference, you can use tools like [Diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/) to check for differences in your files.

Answer (score 1):

The error is when you are taking the substring if the beginning of the string matches `sub`: you should take the substring starting from `sub.length()` and not `str.length()`.

```
public static int strCount(String str, String sub) {
    if (sub.length() > str.length())
        return 0;
    if (str.substring(0, sub.length()).equals(sub))
        return 1 + strCount(str.substring(sub.length()), sub); // <-- sub.length() here
    return strCount(str.substring(1), sub);
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can improve the logic a bit: instead of incrementing going through each character at a time to see if the string begins with `sub`, you can call `indexOf` to retrieve the first index where the string has `sub` appearing.

This would be a sample code:

```
public static int strCount(String str, String sub) {
    int index = str.indexOf(sub);
    if (index == -1) return 0;
    return 1 + strCount(str.substring(index + sub.length()), sub);
}
```